# При изменении языка крашится приложение SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c, sqldeveloper

Установил последнюю версию Oracle developer (20.4.1.407.0006) и 11 Яву на Mac pro 13.3 m1 big sur 11.4 , запускается и работает корректно, но при смене языка (неважно через клавишу или курсором) приложение полностью закрывается. Проверял на новом пользователе, менял язык в оракуле , проверял горячие клавиши, кодировку менял с utf-8 на windows-1251. В чем может быть проблема? Мне нужны 2 языка русский и английский.

Comment: У меня всё работает, только стоит Java 8. Попробуйте откатится.

Comment: Я пробовал устанавливать другие версии - не помогло.  Откатываться некуда это первая установка после покупки на данном маке.